Flutter ERROR:C:\Users\kamde\.gradle\caches\transforms-3
(https://i.sstatic.net/zEqcK.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/ODMms.png)
i have tried all possible solution which is present on stackoverflow
ERROR:C:\Users\kamde.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5bdb5f7eef7e9b20a7c8203d073ae2c1\transformed\jetified-pspdfkit-2024.1.0-runtime.jar: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.YI0: Records are not supported.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform pspdfkit-2024.1.0.aar (com.pspdfkit:pspdfkit:2024.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\kamde.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5bdb5f7eef7e9b20a7c8203d073ae2c1\transformed\jetified-pspdfkit-2024.1.0-runtime.jar.
> Error while dexing.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


just delete transform-3 folder from "C:\Users{user}.gradle\caches"

after that :
Modify android/app/build.gradle to add the following sections in the appropriate
places:
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
android {
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
}

Select Run/Run from the toolbar



dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta02'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
}

android { defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true } }
pls also add this line in build.gradle
